# Sending structs through Unix domain sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, systems-programming

I am using Unix domain sockets to do some interprocess communication in Linux. Upon connection, the client sends a struct using **send** to the server. This struct contains some information about the client including an identifier string at the end. The server receives the info just find and sends another struct back. The client blocks with **recv**, but never gets anything. The server completes the **send** call without any errors and moves on.

Is there something fundamental that I am missing here? When I send strings across the socket both sides send and receive just fine. Does the data have to have a terminating NULL? That does not seem right...

Comment: Are the sockets in datagram or stream mode?

Comment: They are in stream mode.

Comment: Your question implies that this only happens with structs.  Does everything work fine with ints or chars?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing that would be explained in a man page for one of the relevant function calls. Not that it's a bad question for SO, I just would advise you to have a careful look at the documentation while you're waiting for answers.

Comment: What you've described should work fine.  Perhaps try and isolate the problem to a small code sample?

Comment: @ David: The man pages are the first place that I checked and I didn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I came in the next day, I could not reproduce the error again.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the socket on the server.

Comment: I don't see anything besides **close** that could flush a socket.

Comment: Try setting the `flags` argument of the `send()` function to `MSG_EOR`.